# C loss of data or precision is not warned about by compiler

Tags: c, macos, clang, llvm, compiler-warnings

Apple's LLVM does not warn about this problem, even when `-Wall` is specified:

```
uint8_t tta;
typedef uint32_t TT;
TT ttb;
ttb= 0xdeadbeef;
tta = ttb;
// here tta is only 0xEF
```

What can be done to force the compiler to warn about loss of data during assignment?

Comment: It's not loss of precision, but loss of data. And it is completely legal and it is optional for the compiler to issue the warning.

Comment: it does exactly that which you asked it to do: discard the top 3 bytes and squeeze the bottom byte into a variable of `uint8_t`

Comment: The compiler is supposed to warn about *real* problems, like undefined behaviour and such.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yet a similar thing was reported and accepted as a bug in GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2707

Comment: OK sure. If I say tta = ttb>>24 then it is loss of precision.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, my point is that's what `-Wall` does. It doesn't include `-Wconversion` or alike in either GCC or clang...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `-Wconversion` you get a warning:

```
<stdin>:9:7: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'TT' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wconversion]
tta = ttb;
    ~ ^~~
1 warning generated.
```

This was generated by the current release version of Apple's developer tools:

> Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)

Comment: I think it was added in gcc 4.3

Comment: This is with clang.

Comment: Odd that -Wall does not include -Wconversion

Comment: You would think that `-Wnarrowing` might be the more appropriate switch ?

Comment: @fff444: I think it would be deemed too noisy to include this in `-Wall`, since most code is full of such truncating conversions.

Comment: -Wnarrowing This does not cause a warning.

Comment: @fff444: indeed - that was my point - you might expect `-Wnarrowing` here, but it seems you actually need `-Wconversion`.

Comment: You can use `-Weverything` to enable warnings not covered by `-Wall`.